# My Code is answering None. Why is not appending 4 twice?

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I am expecting it append 4 twice but it is displaying None.

```
b = [2,3]
b.append(4)
print(b.append(4))
```

Comment: print `b` later, `append` is an in-place operation

Comment: `b.append(4)` will return `None` and append the number 4 to your list.

Answer (score 0):

**append returns None**

append adds the element but returns none

you can print b later to verify

```py
b = [2,3] 

b.append(4) 

print(b.append(4))

print(b)
```